# RuntimeError when run my python code

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I tried to run my code but I'm faced with this error:

```
File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/niloo/PycharmProjects/untitled/MADRL-master/runners/run_multiwalker.py', wdir='C:/Users/niloo/PycharmProjects/untitled/MADRL-master/runners')

File "C:\Users\niloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\niloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/niloo/PycharmProjects/untitled/MADRL-master/runners/run_multiwalker.py", line 7, in 
from runners import RunnerParser

File "", line 961, in _find_and_load

File "", line 946, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 881, in _find_spec

File "", line 855, in _find_spec_legacy

File "C:\Users\niloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 253, in find_module
fp, pathname, (ext,mode,ty) = imp.find_module(fullname,package_path)

File "C:\Users\niloo\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 269, in find_module
raise RuntimeError("'path' must be None or a list, "

RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please post your whole code here niloofar.

Comment: My code has several files.this is the link of my code :github.com/sisl/MADRL

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the "path" a None or a list as described in the error.

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: Which file is it?  Also you may want to look at this: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: runner>run_multiwalker.py